# Inverse temporal power-law increase of DC voltage under the application of constant DC current

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, power-engineering, supercapacitor, memristor

Is there any material in which the DC voltage follows an inverse temporal power-law increase, under the action of a constant DC current? This implies a situation in which a constant current, I, is the input, such that the output DC voltage, V(t) is proportional to t<sup>m</sup>, where t is time and m is any real number between 0 and 2?

Comment: \$V(t) = a * t^{m}\$. For \$a ≠ 0, m > 1, t → ∞ ⇒ V(t) → ±∞\$. This doesn't seem to make sense in the read world.

Comment: @ Seir, For finite times, it could be possible for all values of m. Also for 0<m<1, it is applicable to even larger time-scales.

Comment: I think you'll have better luck asking this question on [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there any material <-- silicon (formed into transistors and op-amps and diodes and arranged in the right way to make a circuit that does what is wanted). Other materials will be present of course. Basically I'm saying, why not use a circuit? I mean this is an EE site so, surely a circuit must be an option here?

Answer (score 1):

A tungsten light bulb filament approximates this characteristic because as the filament heats up, the resistance increases (nearly proportional to temperature). At very high temperatures (where it glows) heat losses from radiation and condition limit the final levels.

Answer (score 0):

Under the conditions you describe, a capacitor has this characteristic with \$m=1\$.

Comment: An _ideal_ capacitor, as stated in the comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/722444).